# Merge Sort Algorithm fail

Tags: python, python-2.7, segmentation-fault

I wrote a merge-sort algorithm in python. It works perfectly until 10000 numbers but after 10000 it gives me segmentation fault 11. What might be the problem? Any idea about it

```
def merge_count(arr):
    if len(arr) < 2:
        return (arr, 0)
    m = int(len(arr) / 2)
    left, l_counter = merge_count(arr[:m])
    right, r_counter = merge_count(arr[m:])
    return merge(left, right, l_counter + r_counter)


def merge(left, right, counter):
    if len(left) * len(right) == 0:
        return (left + right, counter)
    if left[len(left) - 1] > right[len(right) - 1]:
        val = left.pop(len(left) - 1)
        counter += len(right)
    else:
        val = right.pop(len(right) - 1)
    arr, counter = merge(left, right, counter)

    return (arr + [val], counter)
```

Comment: Segmentation fault? In Python? Just what the heck did you do? Show us the code.

Comment: I added my code @user2357112

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a stack overflow. `merge` uses stack space on the order of the size of the lists to merge, which is way more than Python can handle. Ordinarily, Python would stop you with a `RuntimeError` before you got to that point; you probably used `sys.setrecursionlimit` to go past the safe limit. Stop using `setrecursionlimit`, and rewrite `merge` to not use recursion.

Comment: Yes I used sys.setrecursionlimit. Is there any other way except changing my recursive merge function?

Comment: @GüngörBasa: You could switch to a stackless Python implementation or change the amount of stack space your OS allocates, but not using recursion in `merge` is most likely the best option.